# travis-ci : error during the build (No such file or directory)

Tags: jekyll, travis-ci

I'm having a problem trying to test my build on travis-ci for my jekyll app. One of the plugins generates a json containing informations that my app can reach for a search tool.

The build command works fine on my computer :

```
bundle exec jekyll build --source octopress
```

Witch indexes informations into a search.json file in my built directory (_site).

But it fails on travis-ci as on Heroku.

```
writting search.json to /home/travis/build/alain-andre/mon_site/_site

jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  No such file or directory - /home/travis/build/alain-andre/mon_site/_site/search.json
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: A github repository maybe ?

Comment: Yes [mon_site](https://github.com/alain-andre/mon_site/commit/241b4b78b40155a871b475b32bba4ac67d6165e3). I did a lot of integration test from this question, the good commit is 241b4b78b40155a871b475b32bba4ac67d6165e3

Comment: @AlainANDRE try adding `exclude: [vendor]` in your config.yml? I thought it was a folder not found issue or the way your script is a command but it doesn't look to be an issue. referring to the warning at http://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/

Comment: @AlainANDRE: By looking at your [Travis CI build logs](https://travis-ci.org/alain-andre/mon_site), it seems that you solved your problem with the generation of the `search.json` file. But now I think you are having problems deploying your site to Heroku. From the last build log [#13](https://travis-ci.org/alain-andre/mon_site/builds/62688232#L484), it appears that your are not commiting your site after it was generated hence the updated `search.json` file is not deployed to Heroku. My advice is to commit the generated site before deploying. HTH et bonne chance!

Comment: Thanks both of you for the advises, I was on a startup week end, so I couldn't had a look on this, I'll feedback soon.

Comment: @matrixanomaly I added `exclude:[vendor]` but I had the same problem. So I modified my plugin to generate the `search.json` file in the source directory. 

@dominic-jodoin Now my repo is deployed to Heroku after travis-ci build succeed. 

But I still have a problem : I'm using `Rack::TryStatic` to manage my site on Heroku, I allowed .json in the `try` block but my [site](http://mon-site.herokuapp.com/) does not have access to it (404) so my searching tool is broken ... Any idea of what I could do to access it ? is it a config problem or a location one ?

Comment: @AlainANDRE probably some kind of authentication failure? you have more chance of finding help by posting another question, with the heroku tag. Also, post your solution/workaround as an answer to your own question to help others in the future!

Comment: @matrixanomaly Sure, I'm going to post a new question for this with heroku tag. I'm going to answer this question. This is a build directory problem. As on Heroku than on Travis-ci, the build dir is not the one on my local computer. I feedback this question asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution.

I had to add the `search.json` into the jekyll `site.keep_files`.

First to do is to create a **Jekyll::StaticFile** inside your Jekyll module.

```
class SearchJson < Jekyll::StaticFile
  def write(dest)
    begin
      super(dest)
    rescue
    end

    true
  end
end
```

Then, when your file is created, add it to `site.static_files` like this :

```
# Keep the file from being cleaned by Jekyll
Jekyll::SearchJson.new(site, site.dest, "/", filename)
site.keep_files << filename
```